# Generic Struct in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem in return values `int`/`double` using `void*`.

For example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct list {

  void *info;
  struct list *prox;

} List;

typedef struct queue {

  List* begin;
  List* end;

} Queue;


Queue* create_queue (void) {

 Queue* f = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
 f->begin = f->end = NULL;
 return f;

}


 Queue* insert_queue_end (List* end, void* v) {

 List* p = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
  p->info=v;
  p->prox=NULL;
  if(end!=NULL) {
    end->prox=p;
  }
  return p;
 }

double queue_empty_double(Queue* f) {
   return (f->begin==NULL);
}


double queue_remove_double(Queue* f) {

   List* t;
   double v;


  if(queue_empty_double(f)) {
    exit(1);
  }

   t=f->begin;
   v=*((double*)(t->info));
   f->begin=t->prox;
   if (f->begin==NULL) {
     f->end = NULL;
   }
    free(t);
    printf("%.3lf\n",v);


  }


  void insert_queue(Queue* f, void* v) {

    f->end = insert_queue_end(f->end,v);
    if(f->begin==NULL) {
    f->begin=f->end;
  }

 }

 void print_queue_double(Queue* f) {

  List* i;
  for(i=f->begin;i!=NULL;i=i->prox)
  printf("%.3lf\n",*((double*)i->info));

  }



 int main () {
   Queue* f;
   f = create_queue();
   char ent1[100];
   double n1;
   scanf("%s",ent1);
   while(ent1[0]!='X')
   {
     if(ent1[0]=='E') {
        scanf("%lf",&n1);
        insert_queue(f,&n1);
        scanf("%s",ent1);
    }
    else if (ent1[0]=='D') {
        queue_remove_double(f);
        scanf("%s",ent1);
    }
  }


}
```

But the function doesn't work with `double` values, just with `int`.

Another new code, now the code can print double but in the function queue_remove_double there's a problem, she should remove the first element from a queue and print the first element. I believe this problem is from the generic struct because the function remove the first and print him in a normal struct.

```
Input:
E 1.2
E 2.1
D
X

Output:
1.200

The wrong output:
2.100
```

Comment: By `prox` do you mean `next`? And are you passing in a `double*` or a `double`? That will make a difference. How do you know it doesn't work with double values? Does the compiler throw an error?

Comment: And how do you know when the return value is an `int` (or pointer to `int`) vs a `double` (or pointer to `double`)?  If you're returning a single value, why do you need the `next` (`prox`?) pointer?  If you're returning a list of values, so be it, but maybe you should say so.  How is the space that the `info` member points at allocated?  How is a node (or a whole list of nodes) freed?

Comment: It seems likely there's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) lurking here.  While what you want to do can be done, it is not clear that it can be done as you're trying to do it, and it isn't clear why you're trying to do it in the first place.  So, maybe you need to come up with an example which shows how/why this would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on codeblocks ide. Specify the type of *info to know how to cast the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum DataTypes {
  INTEGER,
  FLOAT,
  DOUBLE,
  CHAR
} DataType;

typedef struct list {
   void *info;
   struct list *next;
   DataType type;
} List;


List* create_list(void *firstInfo, DataType firstType)
{
   List *f=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
   f->info=firstInfo;
   f->type=firstType;
   f->next=NULL;
   return f;
}

List* insertion(List *end, void *data, DataType type)
{
    List *p=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    p->info=data;
    p->next=NULL;
    p->type=type;
    if(end != NULL)
    {
        end->next=p;
    }
    return p;
}

void showTheList(List **theBase)
{
    List *run=*theBase;

    while(run != NULL)
    {
        switch(run->type)
        {
            case INTEGER:
                printf("Showing the value: %d \n",*((int*)run->info));
                break;
            case FLOAT:
                printf("Showing the value: %f \n",*((float*)run->info));
                break;
            case DOUBLE:
                printf("Showing the value: %lf \n",*((double*)run->info));
                break;
            default:
                printf("Showing the value: %c \n",*((char*)run->info));
        }
        run=run->next;
    }
}

List* getEnd(List **theBase)
{
    List *run=*theBase;
    while(run->next != NULL)
        run=run->next;
    return run;
}

void clearList(List **theBase)
{
    List *run=(*theBase)->next;
    free(*theBase);
    while(run != NULL)
    {
        *theBase=run;
        run=run->next;
        free(*theBase);
    }
    *theBase=NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   List *theList=NULL;
   int valA=10;
   float valB=1.25;
   double valC=23.45;
   char valD='C';

   theList=create_list(&valA,INTEGER);

   insertion(getEnd(&theList),&valB,FLOAT);
   insertion(getEnd(&theList),&valC,DOUBLE);
   insertion(getEnd(&theList),&valD,CHAR);

   showTheList(&theList);

   clearList(&theList);
   if(theList == NULL)
     printf("Ok, all operations realized !");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use a cast with the pointer. You need to know the type of the pointer.

```
void print_queue_double(Queue* f) 
{
    List* i;
    for(i=f->begin;i!=NULL;i=i->prox)
    printf("%.3lf\n",*((double*)i->info));
}
```

Comment: Can you see this new function that I put in the code above?  Thank you for these two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pointer. If you use n1, then void * always contain the last n1 value because points to n1. Then when you free the list (queue_remove_double), always is show the value of n1 (the most recent)...

Some Solutions:
(1) Array - showed below - is limited....
(2)New double value with the copy of variable (malloc double) - "ilimited" (limit of your memory...)

In the new double case:

```
List* insert_queue_end (List* end, void* v) {

  List* p = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
  double *data=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)); /*New double new address*/

  *data=*((double*)v); /*Copy the VALUE and not the address to new double in new and fixed address*/
  /*void* points to a new double with a new address in memory */
  p->info=data;

  p->prox=NULL;
  if(end!=NULL) {
    end->prox=p;
  }
  return p;
 }
```

Don't forget to free the memory from the new double in the remove function !

SOME SOLUTIONS:
SOLUTION 1 - The array of doubles:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct list {

  void *info;
  struct list *prox;

} List;

typedef struct queue {

  List* begin;
  List* end;

} Queue;


Queue* create_queue (void) {

 Queue* f = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
 f->begin = f->end = NULL;
 return f;

}

/*Yes the type of return is List* and not Queue* - check your code */    
 List* insert_queue_end (List* end, void* v) {

  List* p = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));

  ///If you want create a new double this is the local - don't use the same address in v !
  p->info=v;

  p->prox=NULL;
  if(end!=NULL) {
    end->prox=p;
  }
  return p;
 }

double queue_empty_double(Queue* f) {
   return (f->begin==NULL);
}


double queue_remove_double(Queue* f) {

   List* t;
   double v;
   double isRemoved=0;

  if(queue_empty_double(f)) {
    exit(1);
  }

   t=f->begin;
   v=*((double*)(t->info));
   f->begin=t->prox;
   if (f->begin==NULL) {
     f->end = NULL;
   }
    free(t);
    printf("%.3lf\n",v);

}


  void insert_queue(Queue* f, void* v) {

    f->end = insert_queue_end(f->end,v);
    if( f->begin==NULL) {
    f->begin=f->end;
  }

 }

void print_queue_double(Queue* f) {

  List* i;
  for(i=f->begin;i!=NULL;i=i->prox)
  printf("%.3lf\n",*((double*)i->info));

  }


 int main () {
   Queue* f;
   f = create_queue();
   char ent1[100];
   ///One Double Allocated - only one address in memory !!!
   ///double n1;

   double listOfDoubles[20]; ///All doubles allocated and one per one have a address in memory !!!
   int countDoubles=0;


   scanf("%s",ent1);
   while(ent1[0]!='X' && countDoubles < 20)
   {
     if(ent1[0]=='E') {

        ///IN YOUR CODE:
        ///Fill the same one double...
        ///scanf("%lf",&n1);

        ///Testing new code
        scanf("%lf",&listOfDoubles[countDoubles]); ///a new double with your address

        ///IN YOUR CODE:
        ///The same address of one variable. The same result.
        ///Remember void * is a pointer and use the address of n1, and then, print the most recent &n1 content...
        ///insert_queue(f,&n1);

        ///A new double in a new address, the content is not equal
        insert_queue(f,&listOfDoubles[countDoubles]);

        countDoubles++;
    }
    else if (ent1[0]=='D') {
        ///free the address and decrement the index of array to reuse a double
        queue_remove_double(f);
        countDoubles--;
    }
    else
    {
        ///Print the list - and see the result "debug"
        print_queue_double(f);
    }
    scanf("%s",ent1);

  }
  free(f);

}
```

SOME SOLUTIONS:
SOLUTION 2 - A new double with the copy of value

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct list {

  void *info;
  struct list *prox;

} List;

typedef struct queue {

  List* begin;
  List* end;

} Queue;


Queue* create_queue (void) {

 Queue* f = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
 f->begin = f->end = NULL;
 return f;

}

 /*Yes the type of return is List* and not Queue* check your code */    
 List* insert_queue_end (List* end, void* v) {

  List* p = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
  double *data=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)); /*New double new address*/

  *data=*((double*)v); /*Copy the VALUE and not the address to new double in new and fixed address*/
  /*void* points to a new double with a new address in memory */
  p->info=data;

  p->prox=NULL;
  if(end!=NULL) {
    end->prox=p;
  }
  return p;
 }

double queue_empty_double(Queue* f) {
   return (f->begin==NULL);
}


double queue_remove_double(Queue* f) {

   List* t;
   double v;
   double isRemoved=0;

  if(queue_empty_double(f)) {
    exit(1);
  }

   t=f->begin;
   v=*((double*)(t->info));
   f->begin=t->prox;
   if (f->begin==NULL) {
     f->end = NULL;
   }
    free(t->info); ///free the double
    free(t);
    printf("%.3lf\n",v);

}


  void insert_queue(Queue* f, void* v) {

    f->end = insert_queue_end(f->end,v);
    if( f->begin==NULL) {
    f->begin=f->end;
  }

 }

void print_queue_double(Queue* f) {

  List* i;
  for(i=f->begin;i!=NULL;i=i->prox)
  printf("%.3lf\n",*((double*)i->info));

  }


 int main () {
   Queue* f;
   f = create_queue();
   char ent1[100];

   double n1;


   int countDoubles=0;


   scanf("%s",ent1);
   while(ent1[0]!='X' && countDoubles < 20)
   {
     if(ent1[0]=='E') {

        scanf("%lf",&n1);
        insert_queue(f,&n1);
    }
    else if (ent1[0]=='D') {
        queue_remove_double(f);
    }
    else
    {
        ///Print the list - and see the result "debug"
        print_queue_double(f);
    }
    scanf("%s",ent1);

  }
  free(f);

}
```